# Java: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: java, mysql

Hello I am currently getting this error:

```
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''gtfs_start_date', 'gtfs_end_date', ) VALUES (396, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, '2015-12' at line 1
```

This works for my other tables, it's when the "Date" is being inserted.

• **MySQL version 5.5.24**

• **gtfs_start_date** and **gtfs_end_date** are both **Date** datatypes in my database.

Here is my query:

```
dbConnection = JdbcBatch.getDBConnection();
dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false);

String query = "INSERT INTO gtfs_calendar(gtfs_service_id, gtfs_monday, gtfs_tuesday, gtfs_wednesday, gtfs_thursday, gtfs_friday, gtfs_saturday, gtfs_sunday, 'gtfs_start_date', 'gtfs_end_date', ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";

preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(query);

preparedStatement.setInt(1, 1);
preparedStatement.setInt(2, 1);
preparedStatement.setInt(3, 1);
preparedStatement.setInt(4, 1);
preparedStatement.setInt(5, 1);
preparedStatement.setInt(6, 1);
preparedStatement.setInt(7, 1);
preparedStatement.setInt(8, 1);                                         
preparedStatement.setDate(9, java.sql.Date.valueOf("2015-12-12"));                          
preparedStatement.setDate(10, java.sql.Date.valueOf("2015-12-12"));

preparedStatement.addBatch();

preparedStatement.executeBatch();
dbConnection.commit();
preparedStatement.clearBatch();
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 4):

You have a extra comma at the end. Remove that as its not required.

```
'gtfs_end_date', )
              ^^^ - this one, remove it.
```

And also, remove the single quotes around the `gtfs_start_date`, `gtfs_end_date`.

```
'gtfs_start_date', 'gtfs_end_date' // single quotes are not required either
```

Comment: Still getting the error!

Comment: Having done both the changes?

Comment: Ah, also removed the single quotes, I forgot that I renamed my date attributes hence not needing the single quotes (reserved)! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is not correct. Remove last comma `,` and single  quotation `''` from last two column name.. Write the query as below.

```
 String query = "INSERT INTO gtfs_calendar(gtfs_service_id, gtfs_monday, 
            gtfs_tuesday,       gtfs_wednesday, gtfs_thursday, gtfs_friday, 
            gtfs_saturday, gtfs_sunday, 
            gtfs_start_date, gtfs_end_date) 
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ";
```